# When should compiler generate move constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, move-semantics

I use VS11 and use following:

```
class ContextWrapper
{
public:

    ContextWrapper()
    {
    } //it should be defaulted I *guess* in order to have automatic move constructor ?
      // no support in VS11 for that now  

    Context* GetContext()
    {
        return this->context.get();
    }

    void SetContext(std::unique_ptr<Context> context)
    {
        this->context = std::move(context);
    }

    //ContextWrapper(ContextWrapper&& other):  context(std::move(other.context))
    //{
    //} // I would like this to be generated by the compiler

private:
    ContextWrapper(const ContextWrapper&);
    ContextWrapper& operator= (const ContextWrapper&);

    std::unique_ptr<Context> context;
};
```

I would like this class to have generated move constructor/assignment. Is the fact that I don't have a trivial constructor the reason I don't get move ? Or there are other factors that influence this ?

Comment: The move constructor is not generated because you declared a copy constructor. Remove the private copy constructor and copy assignment.

Comment: Adding a non-copyable member (like a `unique_ptr`) already prevents generation of the copy special members, so there's no need to prevent them manually, anyway.

Comment: The problem is that if I don't declare copy/assignment private I get an error regarding the private unique_ptr copy constructor. If I don't declare myself the move constructor compiler tries to automatically generate copy and fails

Comment: I don't if VS11 supports it but you could always tell the compiler to generate the move c'tor for you with `T(T&&) = default;`.

Comment: @Ghita The compiler shouldn't automatically generate a copy constructor (and assignment) if you already have a non-copyable member (like a `std::unique_ptr` or a reference), and in fact VC also doesn't. So the only reason the compiler could complain was if you actually tried to copy a `ContextWrapper` in the surrounding code. But adding a private copy constructor doesn't help in this case either, since the usage of your class in the surrounding code is already broken.

Comment: Does standard says if a prohibit copy than I don't have compiler generated move if necessary?

Comment: You would get move members generated if you `= delete`d the copy members. However, VC++ doesn't seem to implement the generation of move members at all yet.

Comment: @ChristianRau but it seems it would expect a copy for in cases where I have code like container.emplace_back Wrapper. Having a move ctr does solve the problem here.

Comment: @Ghita Yeah, indeed from the other answers it seems VC2012 is still not auto-generating move-members. I thought this already works in 2012 but was at error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This part of C++11 is unfortunately in flux.  And whatever the standard is going to say, VC11 couldn't possibly implement it yet.  So for today, I don't believe you'll be able to count on generated move members.

However, this is a good question and I wanted to get a good answer out on it.

In general, the compiler should generate move members if you have no user-declared copy members nor destructor.  `= default` and `= delete` counts as user-declared.  If you declare one move member (e.g. move constructor), the other will not be implicitly generated.

Unfortunately C++11 goes on to say that sometimes the move members are implicitly deleted when declared with `=default`, and sometimes their generation depends upon whether the bases and members have move members or are trivially copyable.  This is all way too complicated and sometimes gives surprising behavior.  Here is the CWG issue tracking this bug:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1402

As I write this, the issue does not have the correct proposed resolution.  I expect that to change in about a week.  At the 2012 Fall C++ standards meeting in Portland, OR, an agreement was reached which basically says:

1. The compiler will never implicitly delete move members.
2. The implicit generation of the move members will always be the same thing as `= default`.
3. Implicit generation will not depend upon the triviality of the bases or members, nor whether or not they may throw when moved.

In a nutshell, I expect the corrected wording of CWG 1402 to simply say:

> In general, the compiler should generate move members if you have no
>   user-declared copy members nor destructor.  `= default` and `= delete`
>   counts as user-declared.  If you declare one move member (e.g. move
>   constructor), the other will not be implicitly generated.
>   And if you `=default` a move member, you'll get something that moves
>   each base and member.

(in proper standardize).  I have not yet seen the wording that will say this.  Jason Merrill is writing it up for us.

This will mean that sometimes the compiler will implicitly generate throwing move members.  But we were going for simple rules that nevertheless did the right thing most of the time (few surprises).

Comment: well, the idea of foundations that you can *rely on*, that are fully *predictable*, disappeared already with text mode streams (yielding the über-silly situation of not being able to write `cat` in Windows in standard C++ (and let's not get into `echo`)). so i think this clarification that is going on wrt. move semantics, is not that important, really. it is about the complicated details of an optimization that, with the possibility of throwing move constructors, is already unreliable in the sense of introducing extra failure modes -- so that the details don't really matter.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf the details can be important because you count on it for performance. Luckyly one could write a compile time assertion about the existence of a no throw move availability as far as I can tel

Answer (score 4):

To more directly answer this, Visual Studio does not support any version of implicit move constructor/assignment generation. So you have to manually write them out, always.

Comment: And I thought they fixed that in 2012.

Comment: @ChristianRau: No, but given what Howard said, it's probably good that they waited.