# move assignment not called for vector element

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to c++11 and I am trying to experiment with move semantics and rvalue function parameters.
I do not understand why the following code won't compile:

```
class MatchEntry
{
  unique_ptr<char []> key;

public:
  MatchEntry() {}

  MatchEntry(const char *key_bytes, int key_nbytes) {
    char *data = new char[key_nbytes];
    copy(key_bytes, key_bytes + key_nbytes, data);
    key = unique_ptr<char []>(data);
  }

};

void add_entry(vector<MatchEntry> v, MatchEntry&& e, int index) {
  v[index] = e;
}
```

`class MatchEntry` has a `unique_ptr` member and therefore no implicit copy assignment operator can be generated by the compiler. However a move assignment operator is generated. The `add_entry` function takes a rvalue reference to a `MatchEntry` and therefore I expected the move assignment to be called. But I get the following error when I try to compile:

```
gg.cpp: In function ‘void add_entry(std::vector<MatchEntry>, MatchEntry&&, int)’:
gg.cpp:57:12: error: use of deleted function ‘MatchEntry& MatchEntry::operator=(const MatchEntry&)’
   v[index] = e;
            ^
gg.cpp:32:7: note: ‘MatchEntry& MatchEntry::operator=(const MatchEntry&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class MatchEntry
       ^
gg.cpp:32:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>&) [with _Tp = char; _Dp = std::default_delete<char []>]’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:81:0,
                 from gg.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unique_ptr.h:599:19: note: declared here
       unique_ptr& operator=(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should compiler generate a move constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13174973/845092)

Comment: @MooingDuck No, the issue is simply that named rvalue references, like `e`, are lvalues.

Comment: @T.C.: You're definitely right.  I'm half certain I'm still also right.

Comment: What T.C. said ... you need `v[index] = std::move(e);`. But even then `add_entry` is pointless because you're operating on a local copy of the `vector`.

Comment: And the string copy is incorrect, the trailing '`\0`' has been left out

Comment: @AaronMcDaid this is not a string this is meant to be a char array

Comment: @MooingDuck this is not a duplicate, in my case the move constructor is being generated by the compiler

Comment: @AntoninBas, ah OK. So you are not going to use it as a string, e.g. with `cout << e.key << endl;`?

Comment: @T.C. add_entry is meant to be a method of a class which has the vector as an attribute. I was just trying to make the code smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before directly discussing the compilation error, you should definitely take `v` by reference in this fuction.

```
void add_entry(vector<MatchEntry> &v, MatchEntry&& e, int index) {
                         //       |
                         //       `--- by reference here
  v.at(index) = std::move(e);
}
```

Anyway, the problem is the `e` is an lvalue, and therefore the assignment was trying to use copy assignment instead of move assignment. A named variable is always an lvalue, regardless of whether its type is `MatchEntry` or `MatchEntry&` or `MatchEntry&&`. Of course, we know that the object referenced by `e` was an rvalue, and therefore we can use `move` to tell the compiler to treat `e` as an rvalue.

(Unrelated: but I always like to access vectors with `.at(index)`. It's safer due to the bounds-checking.)