# Vector of elements containing std::threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I've got a class `Tester` containing an `std:thread` object, and an `std::vector` of `Tester`. I understand that I can't copy threads, so the `push_back` is out of the question, but why `emplace_back` is not working? Where is the copy in my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <unistd.h>

class Tester
{
public:
    Tester(std::function<void(void)> func) : 
        th(func)
    {
    }

    ~Tester()
    {
        th.join()
    }

private:
    std::thread th;
};

std::vector<Tester> testers;

void InnerHelloWorld()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from the inner word!\n";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        testers.emplace_back(InnerHelloWorld);
    }

    sleep(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, you can test it here: https://repl.it/repls/QuietTidyScientificcomputing

Comment: You have to write a move constructor, it isn't implicitly declared here.

Comment: As an aside, `push_back` works fine with rvalues (i.e. if you have a move c'tor), though I'd prefer `emplace_back ` here for style reasons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Theres a couple of minor issues in your code

You missed the trailing semi-colon off of:

```
th.join()
```

But importantly, you need to give your class a move constructor - the default one is fine:

```
Tester(Tester&&) = default;
```

This is needed as when vectors resize themselves they need to move or copy their elements. A move constructor will *generally* be created for you but in your case having a custom destructor supresses it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174973/when-should-compiler-generate-move-constructor).

This will let your code compile, but then it'll throw an exception at runtime. This is because you sometimes destruct from moved-from `Testers` which will call join on a moved from thread. Fortunately this is an easy fix:

```
~Tester()
 {
   if(th.joinable())
       th.join();
 }
```

Full working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

#include <unistd.h>

class Tester
{
  public:
  Tester(std::function<void(void)> func) : 
    th(func)
  {
  }

  ~Tester()
  {
    if(th.joinable())
        th.join();
  }

  Tester(Tester&&) = default;

  private:
  std::thread th;
};

std::vector<Tester> testers;

void InnerHelloWorld()
{
  std::cout << "Hello from the inner word!\n";
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

  for(size_t i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
  {
    testers.emplace_back(InnerHelloWorld);
  }

  sleep(1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This ALMOST solved my problem... In my real code I've got a `std::thread` AND a `std::atomic_bool`, for which no copy constructor is defined, neither an rvalue one

Comment: @MikeVine FWIW, the user-declared destructor prevents implicit declaration of a move c'tor.

Comment: @ErniBrown Putting an `atomic` into a vector is almost certainly a bad idea (unless e.g. the vector capacity does not change). Atomics are used for thread synchronization, and that means their address must be stable. The reason that atomics are not copy-constructible is that copying a variable cannot be implemented atomically on any common hardware safe for using locks, BTW. While that is easy to work around by providing a custom definition for the move c'tor, you should really rethink your design.

Comment: @ArneVogel Thank you, I solved using a vector of unique_ptr pointing to the objects.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define move constructor for your class so it becomes *MoveInsertable*  and will satisfy requirements of `emplace` method:

```
Tester(Tester && other) : 
    th(::std::move(other.th))
{
}
```

Another problem that will arise once you fix lack of move constructor is an attempt to join thread that is not nessesery joinable since actual thread could have been moved into another object. So you need to add a corresponding check:

```
~Tester()
{
   if(th.joinable())
   {
       th.join();
   }
}
```